# How would one write a data-score attribute in haml for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, haml

For instance, in erb:

```
<div class= "review-rating" data-score="<%= review.rating %>"></div>
```

I can't figure out how write this in haml. I've used a converter but it returned the data-score as empty quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.review-rating{ 'data-score': review.rating }`

Comment: Don't know how it will be in slim?)